# How to re-use sequence values as foreign key in PostgreSQL DML SQL file?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create an SQL file to insert test data into my database. I have a global sequence for the entire database and I'd like to use it here as well.

For this, when creating the PK `id` fields, I use `nextval("mySeq")`. To reference this later in an FK, I can use `currval("mySeq")`. The problem comes when I'm creating a table with multiple FKs. In that case I need more than one previous values from the sequence.

Here is a little example:

```
insert into table1 (id) values( nextval("seq") );
insert into table2 (id) values( nextval("seq") );
insert into table3 (id) values( nextval("seq") );

insert into table_sum (table1_FK, table2_FK, table3_FK) values ( ????????????? )
```

What can / should I do in this case? If this is not the right way to do this, I'm interested in alternative solutions as well. :)

Comment: so if you insert 4 rows, you will need to pupulate table_sum with 4 columns?..

Comment: That looks like a really strange design

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why? I'm open for better solutions, but what is strange about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  t1 as (insert into table1 (id) values( nextval("seq") ) returning id),
  t2 as (insert into table2 (id) values( nextval("seq") ) returning id),
  t3 as (insert into table3 (id) values( nextval("seq") ) returning id)
insert into table_sum (table1_FK, table2_FK, table3_FK)
  select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id from t1, t2, t3;
```

Obviously it will work only for single row. If you want to insert multiple rows in one statement then you should to join CTEs in a some way.